# Postfix and Subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, mx-record

I set up Postfix on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. However, I am not sure where I have to use the subdomain and where the domain. Let us call them `mail.example.com` and `example.com` respectively.

The system is a null client, sending emails but not receiving any (implemented via `inet_interfaces = loopback-only` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`). I intend to send messages from `noreply@example.com` exclusively.

- The MX record is `@ IN MX 0 mail.example.com`.
- A records for both `@` and `mail` point to the Postfix server.
- The TLS certificates mentioned in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` refer to `mail.example.com`: `smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem` and
  `smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem`.
- With `smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic` I rewrite `user@hostname` to `noreply@mail.example.com` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.
- I added `masquerade_domains = example.com` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to replace the `mail.example.com` in `noreply@mail.example.com` with `example.com`. Somehow, that does not work. Emails still arrive from sender `noreply@mail.example.com`.

The questions are accordingly:

- Do I have to use `@` or `mail` in the MX record?
- Do the TLS certificates have to refer to refer to `mail.example.com` or to `example.com`?
- Should `/etc/postfix/generic` first convert `user@hostname` into `noreply@mail.example.com` or directly into `noreply@example.com`?

Comment: If this system is not meant to receive mail, why have you directed incoming mail to it in the MX record?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for the comment. I read that mail servers commonly refuse to communicate with servers that do not have a MX record. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Not having an MX record is completely legitimate, so I don't know why any mail server would do that. Maybe some do. Of course, not having an MX record means that incoming mail goes to the same host; the MX record is intended to divert incoming email elsewhere.

Comment: That is good to know. Thanks. Do you also happen to have comments on the other questions?

Comment: Most everything you have asked so far relates to _incoming_ mail, and what little remains will probably change depending on what you actually want, to wit: Exactly what do you intend to do with incoming mail?

Comment: If you are concerned about people *"refusing to communicate"* with you.. then *"sending emails but not receiving any"* is the first thing you need to address..

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was planning on simply rejecting incoming mail, not admitting it into the server at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most correct way to do this nowadays is to create an account on the proper mail service which is fully configured to serve `example.com`. (Of course, this could be your own server, this doesn't matter.) Then, on your null host, you only configure mail server as a smart host, with SASL authentication.

While it is perfectly possible to set up Postfix like this (there are plenty of manuals out there, including Postfix's own), I think Postfix is overkill for such use. Consider using `nullmailer`, which is suited exactly for systems which don't do anything with mail except originate some system notifications.

If that is not possible, set up DNS like this:

- `example.com` MX record points to its proper mail service. It has nothing to do with subdomains.
- `nullhost.example.com. MX 10 .`, i.e. point to nowhere. This is explicit indication that you don't intend to receive any mail for `anything@nullhost.example.com`. This is not requred if you protect null host's smtpd service from outside connections (firewall `tcp/25`, listen on `localhost:25` only, etc.); however, explicit is always better than implicit.
- this null host is going to send mail which sets `example.com` as sender domain, so its mail must obey DMARC settings for that domain. Otherwise correctly behaving receivers will drop its mail.

This last point, DMARC, could complicate things considerably. If it is set securely, which means the record looks like `_dmarc.example.com. TXT "v=DMARC1; p=reject; pct=100; ..."`, you'll need to set up SPF and DKIM signing on the null host. SPF is easy, just add "a:nullhost.example.com" into SPF TXT record. DKIM is challenging, you'll need to create additional DKIM key pair, choose a selector (`nullhost` probably will do), install it's public pair into DNS as `nullhost._domainkey.example.com. TXT "... key data ..."`. Then configure singning with corresponding private key directly on the null host (and use the chosen selector), I'd employ opendkim for that. Did I mentioned using smart host is preferred method?

---

And, your questions.

- You are not the server (you said you this system shouldn't receive any mail). So you don't need any TLS Server certificate. You may set up things using TLS Client certificate, so when you connect to your smart host or to other servers via TLS you'll be able to present it. But why would you want to do that?
- The "apex" record `@ MX`, a.k.a. `example.com. MX`, must be directed to example.com's **m**ail e**x**changer (the system which receives mail for `something@example.com`). It has nothing to do with mail for any subdomain. Each subdomain is mail domain on its own.
- How you set up address rewriting is up to you. The only thing outside world sees is the final result. So why bother doing it in two steps?

Comment: That is a very insightful answer. Thank you.